# Ошибка запуска qtcreator.exe (0xc0000005)

Tags: c++, windows, qtcreator, windows-7

При нажатии на qtcreator.exe получаю ошибку 0xc0000005 и собственно запустить среду нереально , пробовал отключать антивирус, запускать от имени администратора, проверял на наличие злокачественных обновлений . Проверял ЖД на наличие драйверов и пк на общую целосность драйверов , но к сожалению это ничего не дало (И да я перезагружал пк).

Comment: Либо не указан путь к библиотекам приложения, либо надо заново переустановить

Answer (score 1):

Поддержку Windows7 прекратили, официальная сборка Qt6 требует Windows10.

Документация: [qt6-development-hosts-and-targets](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt6-development-hosts-and-targets), [supported-platforms](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/supported-platforms.html).